# automated emails

Tags: email, sharepoint-email, scheduled-tasks

I am sending daily emails to provide dietary advice to people in a research study over an 8-week period, with each daily email being different (although the same for all people). It would appear that I can do this using gmail with an app through google docs.

Is there a SharePoint solution to send these 56 templated emails on a daily schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Sending scheduled emails from SharePoint could be accomplished with a workflow.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/09/18/step-by-step-sending-email-messages-from-a-workflow-in-an-app-for-sharepoint-2013/

Alternatively, you could use powershell to generate the emails along with tasks scheduler to set the distribution times.

http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/powershell-sending-email-with-gmail-example/